# Class is inaccessible due to its protection level only when publishing

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

VisualStudio 2022 is being weird when compiling my project (A) with reference to another project. (B)

When I build A, it succeeds without issues. When I try to publish A, I get:

> 3>'DbWatcher' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Cleaning both projects does not fix the problem. I can run the basic build in both Debug and Release mode without failure.

The failure comes after:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
... /platform:x64 /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:...
/reference:...\projectB\obj\Release\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0\win-x64\ref\projectB.dll /reference:....
/debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+
/out:obj\Release\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0\win-x64\projectA.dll
...
/target:...
```

Comment: Are you running tests as part of publishing?

Comment: @JonathanDodds No, I'm not.

Comment: Do you have an error code with the message? Is this a [CS0122](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122) error? Is `DbWatcher` part of Project A or Project B?